# Merging two PR's

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

I am a new developer and just starting to ramp up my PR's at work. So I made a PR and before that PR was merged I made another PR. My first PR was finally approved and merged but the second PR doesnt have the changes from the first one. So I am wondering if I merge the second PR without the changes of the first PR will this override my first PR's changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a bit of a sketchy operation to me. If you're unsure, here's what I suggest.

Suppose your first PR was merged to `origin/master` and your second PR is on branch `pr2`. Then I'd do the following:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull --rebase origin master`
3. `git checkout pr2`
4. `git rebase master`

Briefly, I'm suggesting you sync your local master branch with upstream, then rebase your `pr2` branch on master. This essentially applies the novel commits in master before your novel commits in `pr2`. At this stage, you'll find out if you get any merge conflicts. If not, you can examine/test your project and decide if merging your PR will be safe.